# Get URL Up to a Specific Point (jQuery/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jQuery/JavaScript that I use for language selection which will get the URL and then append the relevant language selection syntax to the end of it. Please see below:

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var url = jQuery(location).attr('href') + '?___store=default&___from_store=default';
    jQuery(".english").attr("href", (url));
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="languageselection">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a class="english">English</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This works great and does what I need it to, unless a user was to select a language and then try to move back to another language. This is because the `?___store=default&___from_store=default` is added twice onto the URL. Resulting in the following URL:

www.example.com/product.html?___store=default&___from_store=default?___store=default&___from_store=default

So my query is whether it's possible to amend my jQuery variable so that it only gets the URL up to the `.html` point of the URL? This will result in the language syntax only ever being added once.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname` to get what you want. See Location object : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to get current url. Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
//jquery
$(location).attr('href');

//pure javascript
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

// to show it in an alert window
alert(window.location);
});
```

There is also this function that may help when determining absolute paths.

```
function getAbsolutePath() {
var loc = window.location;
var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(0, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
return loc.href.substring(0, loc.href.length - ((loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).length - pathName.length));
```

}